# Scrapy + Change in request parameter

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using `Scrapy` to crawl through a website. The links I need to crawl are of the form `http://www.somesite.com/details.html?pageId=<some_integer_id>`. The value of `some_integer_id` extends from `1` to `100` (not 100 exactly). What I do is this:

1.I create a function to generate a list of urls:

```
def generateURLs(self):
    url_list = []
    for i in range(1, 101):
        url_list.append('http://www.somesite.com/details.html?pageId=%d' % i)
    return url_list
```

2.Use this function to set the value of `start_urls` of `Scrapy` like this:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.start_urls = self.generateURLs()
```

Is this the recommended way to use `Scrapy` or is there any other better way to do this when I just need to change a value of a request parameter?

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, this is the only right way to do this. Scrapy's BaseSpider needs `start_urls` to find urls to crawl. This means if you really don't like this, you could [override](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.BaseSpider.start_requests) the `start_requests()` function to generate your requests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This method sounds fine, there is no "golden" method.

However, considering Scrapy calls start_requests you could opt for an override of start_requests like:

```
def start_requests(self):
    for i in range(1, 101):
        yield Request(url='http://www.somesite.com/details.html?pageId={0}'.format(i), callback=self.my_callback)
```

Effect is the same, with less code.